# Merge 2 SRV into one

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I have 2 textures in 2 different ShaderResourceViews. What's the fastest/least expensive way to merge them into one? I would use [CopySubresourceRegion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476394.aspx) but copying a texture is quite a bit expensive.

Comment: What do you mean by merging? Copying is already very efficient and I doubt that you can get much faster if you really need to copy.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Is there any way to let one SRV point to multiple textures that are already in video memory?

Comment: Do you mean a texture array?

Comment: Oh you don't say.. I have 2 textures in 2 instances of ID3DTexture2D, and i wanna combine them into single SRV. My question is, what's the fastest way of doing it